# ip tables 127.0.0.1 to ipv4.fiddler

Tags: linux, windows, port, iptables

Hi I want to use Telerik Fiddler to analyze some https packets but I have no source code of the targeted program thus I can't change all their URLs.

The information I want to get is the full URL and body.

Would this be possible with IP tables on Linux?
Or maybe there is even something for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that Proxifier for Windows/Mac can archive this.

This app allows me to run a target program with a specific proxy and it allows to forward the loopback interface (localhost) as well!